# Can we inference the relationship of two classes from their restrictions?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, owl, ontology, inference

I'm not sure if we can inference relationship of two classes from their restrictions... if we have 2 classes:

```
owl:class1 rdfs:subClassOf [restriction1...], [restriction2...], [restriction3].

owl:class2 rdfs:subClassOf [restriction1...], [restriction2...].
```

What inference can we draw from this knowledge? It looks like `owl:class2` is broader than `owl:class1`. Can we inference `owl:class1 rdfs:subClassOf owl:class2.`?

Comment: @AKSW can we treat restrctionClass same as class here?

Comment: What this says is that given `class3 ≡ restriction1 ⊓ restriction2`, `class1 ⊑ class3` and `class2 ⊑ class3`. If that's your definition of "*broader*", than this is inferable. It, however, does not mean that `class1` and `class2` need to share even a single individual. Think of e.g. professors and students which all have a name (res1) and a surname (res2), but there's usually no overlap between the two sets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> owl:class1 rdfs:subClassOf [restriction1...], [restriction2...], [restriction3].
>
> owl:class2 rdfs:subClassOf [restriction1...], [restriction2...].
> ```
>
> What inference can we draw from this knowledge? It looks like
>   owl:class2 is broader than owl:class1. Can we inference owl:class1
>   rdfs:subClassOf owl:class2.?

That wouldn't be a legal inference at all.  Remember, subclass relationships are just sub-set relationships on sets of individuals.  Restriction expressions are just class expressions, which means that they denote sets of individuals.  When you're looking at some axioms, you don't know *everything*, you just know some things that people have stated.  E.g., I can tell you that

A ⊆ {1,2,3,4,5}
    A ⊆ {1,2,3,4}
    A ⊆ {2,3,4,5}

and

B ⊆ {1,2,3,4,5}
    B ⊆ {1,2,3,4}

Now, we have more subset axioms about A than about B, and all the ones about B also apply to A.  It doesn't have to be the case that A ⊆ B, though.  E.g., it could be the case that:

A = {2,3,4}
    B = {2,3}

Comment: It's worth noting that the inference would be valid if class2 was defined as equivalent to the intersection of the two restrictions.

Comment: thank you for your answer, base on this, what inference can we draw of two things from their relationship with other classes? can we only inference information base on property's domain and range?

Comment: @Ignazio little bit confuse here, i thought subclass of multiple classes can be understand as the intersection of multiple classes since classes are represented as set

Comment: @Charles being a subclass of several sets doesn't imply being exactly their intersection.  [1] is subset of [0,1,2] and of [1,2,3],but their intersection is [1,2],not [1].

Comment: @Charles as Joshua said, subclass of multiple classes means _subclass_ of the intersection of the classes.